# Remove white spaces from the left and right sides of a string on PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I always have problems with strings full of weird characters that are not white spaces but they do count as an element of the string. How can I remove all this characters from the string (not removing inner spaces)?

I am using preg_replace, but it eliminates inner spaces which I want to keep.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Php shows that "My string" has 40 elements

```
string(40)=>"
     My string
"
```

And it should have only 9 just like that:

```
string(9)=>"My string"
```

This spaces at the beginning and end of the word are not feed, enter or tab since I've used string replace just like that:

```
str_replace("\r", "", $string);
str_replace("\t", "", $string);
str_replace(char(10), "", $string);
```

Comment: Are the extra characters whitespace or not? The title says "Remove white spaces", but then your question says "weird characters that are not white spaces". What are the characters? You can do `echo ord($string[$i])` to see the character code of character `$i` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the trim function

Example

```
$bad_text = "\t\tWhitespace is bad!!!  ";
var_dump($bad_text);
$good_text = trim($bad_text);
var_dump($good_text);
```

Comment: It doesn't work the test still bad. There is some garbage I can't eliminate using trim.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string that you're trying to work with?